# Typescript does not correctly detect generic types: Type Entity | null is not assignable to type T | null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea

I have a generic React component like below:

```js
export const QueryInputDropDown = <T extends unknown, I extends unknown>(props: {
    label: string;
    query?: (input?: I) => Promise<T[]>;
    queryInput: I | undefined;
    mapper?: (t: T) => Entity;
    selectedItem?: T | null;
    setSelectedItem?: (x: T | null) => void;
}) => {
...
}
```

When I use it, even if I pass correct data types, typescript (and my IDE, IntelliJ IDEA) complains that type `number|undefined` is not assignable to `I|undefined` or type `Entity|null` is not assignable to `T|null`. How can I fix this?

Example of call:

```
<QueryInputDropDown
    query={RpcMethods.getCompanyUsers}
    queryInput={company?.id}
    label={"Responsible"}
    selectedItem={resp}
    setSelectedItem={setResp}
/>
```

P.S: If I explicitly specify types like below, errors are gone. But how can I have TS engine detect them automatically?

```
<QueryInputDropDown<Entity, number>
                        query={RpcMethods.getCompanyUsers}
                        queryInput={company?.id}
                        label={"Responsible"}
                        selectedItem={resp}
                        setSelectedItem={setResp}
                    />
```